# Ordering foreign keys without removing the duplicates keys

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table called courses and courses has relation to country table

The table courses have `name,country_id(FK)`

A result like this

| id | course_name | country_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | course1 | 1 |
| 2 | course2 | 1 |
| 3 | course3 | 1 |
| 4 | course4 | 2 |
| 5 | course5 | 2 |
| 6 | course6 | 2 |
| 7 | course7 | 3 |
| 8 | course8 | 3 |

What I want to achieve is to order the courses based on country_id without duplicates in the same order
like this

| id | course_name | country_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | course1 | 1 |
| 2 | course2 | 2 |
| 3 | course3 | 3 |
| 4 | course4 | 1 |
| 5 | course5 | 2 |
| 6 | course6 | 3 |
| 7 | course7 | 1 |
| 8 | course8 | 2 |

How can I achieve this in eloquent?

**Update2**: I'm getting the courses in pagination way, so I want to get courses without duplicate the country per page

Comment: please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and make a [mre]

Comment: so you order only the third column and the rest not?

Comment: by default, I'm ordering the country_id but I want to get courses per country without duplicate the country per page

Comment: @nbk yes, I want to order only the country_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT course_name, 
                 country_id,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country_id ORDER BY course_name) rn1,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY course_name) rn2
          FROM cources ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT course_name, 
                 country_id,
                 rn2,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rn1, course_name) rn3
          FROM cte1 )          
SELECT cte1.course_name, cte2.country_id
FROM cte1
JOIN cte2 ON cte1.rn2 = cte2.rn3
ORDER BY cte1.course_name
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8eb0d00560eebc7f4fad2cb669a79e0b

---

> your assumes that the country_ids are sorted numbers but if they aren't [dbfiddle.uk/…](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=452ac2aaf256bb2eb9fe80bffd8cdba3) – nbk

This can be easily fixed by according `ORDER BY` adjusting in `cte2`:

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT course_name, 
                 country_id,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country_id ORDER BY course_name) rn1,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY course_name) rn2
          FROM cources ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT course_name, 
                 country_id,
                 rn2,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rn1, country_id) rn3
          FROM cte1 )          
SELECT cte1.course_name, cte2.country_id
FROM cte1
JOIN cte2 ON cte1.rn2 = cte2.rn3
ORDER BY cte1.course_name
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1ae20ca7eb414d7c049d2643a092254f

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need but do u know how to convert it to laravel eloquent?

Comment: @EyadJaabo *do u know how to convert it to laravel eloquent?* no, I do not use Laravel.

Comment: your assumes  that the country_ids are sorted numbers but if they aren't https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=452ac2aaf256bb2eb9fe80bffd8cdba3

Comment: @nbk This can be easily fixed by according ORDER BY adjusting. `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rn1, country_id) rn3` in `cte2`.

Comment: i know, i wanted only to give you a hint to improve your anwer